# Getting Error Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in

Tags: php

Getting two errors with this code.

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>
> Warning: Division by zero in...NAN%

```html
<ul class="list list-icons list-icons-style-3 list-primary">
  <li><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> <strong>Entries:</strong> <?php echo $show_enter; ?> -  <strong>Attended:</strong> <?php echo $show_attended; ?> -  <strong>Percent Turnout:</strong> 
    <?php
        if($percent = ($show_attended/$show_enter)*100){
            echo round_out($percent) . '%';
        }else{
            echo '%';
        }
    ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are `$show_attended` and `$show_enter` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This issue occurs when you try to divide a number by zero. Because divide any number by zero is undefined.

Here `$show_enter` has 0 value. That's the problem. I don't know where `$show_enter` is coming from, So you need to debug `$show_enter`.

**But** in your system Is there any possibilities `$show_enter` to have 0 value, Then you need to fix this calculation issue by using condition.

```
<ul class="list list-icons list-icons-style-3 list-primary">
    <li><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> <strong>Entries:</strong> <?php echo $show_enter; ?> -  <strong>Attended:</strong> <?php echo $show_attended; ?> -  <strong>Percent Turnout:</strong> 
    <?php
    if(!empty($show_enter)){
        echo round_out(($show_attended/$show_enter)*100) . '%';
    }else{
        echo '%';
    }
    ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you yes that fixed it perfectly. The issue was that $show_entry initially has a value of 0 until after the show has been posted.